# Laravel application on the AWS ElasticBeanstalk is not connecting to the RDS database

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have deployed my Laravel application to the AWS ElasticBeanstalk. I am trying to connect to the RDS database from the application. Database credentials are set as env variables in the BeanstalkEnvironment. But it is not working. This is what I have done so far.

I created an RDS database in the same VPC as Elasbeanstalk's EC2 instances.

[image]

Then I set the environment variables as follows:

[image]

When I run my application, it is throwing error "Unknown database 'laratest'". What is wrong with my configuration?

The following is the Inbound Rules of the security group of the RDS database:

[image]

As you can see it is allowing TCP connection on port 3306 from SG of the EC2 instances. Also allowing all the traffic too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the following checklist:

1. Check for the database name: It's not the same as the identifier. Under "configuration" tab, look for "DB name". Use that as the name of the database when trying to connect.
2. The security group of the RDS instance allows TCP connections from the security group of the Elastic ElasticBeanstalk application on port 3306. Read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html).
3. Although you have mentioned that the two services are provisioned in the same VPC, if you have setup the VPC, ensure that there is a open line of connection between the two subnets, if you are not sharing subnets. In most of the cases this is present by default (eg if you are using CDK to set them up) but this would be my next checkbox.

Also, note that a better way to lock down RDS instances is to use IAM based authentication. So you don't have to worry about exposing the credentials anywhere and AWS takes care of the authentication. Read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html).

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question. Please have a look. It still does not work.

Comment: Are you able to zero down to where does the problem lie? Is it in connecting to the database or finding the right database to connect to? Are you using the right database name ?

Comment: The database name is DB Identifier as you can see in the screenshot. I think I am using the right one.

Comment: I've updated the answer, do you mind checking if that solves the problem ?

Comment: Thanks. That works. The issue with the DB name. I thought the DB identifier is the DB name. Confusing.